# Why doesn't R recognize the cat_plot command?

Tags: r, plot, categorical-data, interaction

I have run this code before and it has worked. Now, I need to replicate the graphs in gray scale, but the command for cat_plot is inexplicably failing.

My analysis runs the following basic regression:

```
m1 <- lm(y1 ~ M + E + C + G + G*M + G*E + G*C, data = dat)
```

Every variable in the model is categorical. Previously, I used the following code to produce a graph with cat_plot that compares the predicted outcomes when M = 0 and M = 1 for the two groups: G = 0 and G = 1.

```
library(jtools)
cat_plot(m1, geom = "bar", interval = TRUE,  pred = M, modx = G, plot.points = FALSE, 
         errorbar.width = .2, int.width =.95,
         int.type = "confidence",
         pred.values = c(0,1),
         line.thickness = 1.2,
         pred.labels = c(0,1),
         modx.labels = c("G = 0", "G = 1"))
```

And whereas previously this worked, now it returns the following error:

```
Error in cat_plot(m3, geom = "bar", interval = TRUE, pred = mobilization,  : 
  could not find function "cat_plot"
```

I need to recreate the original plot, and specify that I want it in gray scale rather than in color. But WHY am I getting this error? I have tried uninstalling and installing jtools, I have installed and loaded rlang, restarted started R again. I have even used an old version of R to see if some kind of update is throwing a wrench in things. Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: The `jtools` documentation says that in the recent versions `cat_plot` is now part of a package called `interactions`

Comment: That function is not in the current version of `jtools`. I see it listed in the functions from version 1.

Comment: rdocumentation.org is a good resource for problems like this - searching for [cat_tools](https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=cat_plot&latest=) shows the `interactions` package as the first hit, and the 2nd hit is a `jtools` page for "deprecated functions", saying that `cat_tools` (and a few other functions) have moved to the `interactions` package.